# Thinning out the numerator in the quotient of two sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ are two real monotonely increasing sequences with $a_n, b_n\to\infty$. Suppose further there is $c_0\ge 0$ such that $$\frac{a_n}{b_n}\to c_0.$$

Under which conditions is it then true that for any $c > c_0$ there is a subsequence $(a_{k_n})$ such that $$\frac{a_{k_n}}{b_n}\to c \; ?$$

Comment: You can reduce the problem to the two cases $c_0=0$ and $c_0=1$.  An interesting base case is $a_n=b_n$ with $c_0=1$. Try to answer for that case, first.

Answer (score 3):

Take $a_n = b_n = 2^n$, and $c$ not a power of two.  You will need some condition limiting the growth rate of $a_n$.  I wonder if perhaps concavity is sufficient?

Comment: Thank you. I edited the question to ask for sufficient conditions.

Comment: It feels like you can suffice to say $b_n<\alpha n$ for some $\alpha$, which is a bit weaker than concavity.